# React JS cannot Update the record

Tags: reactjs

i have create the simple crud system in React with Laravel. i shall be able to add the records and view the records but couldn't update the records. what i tried so far i attached below. i attached the full code for easy for understanding. i think the problem is occur in the update url is there any error. Api i tested through the console it is working well in update part

i attached the when i looked at the console

```
    127.0.0.1:8000/api/update/undefined:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

**Full code**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {useEffect, useState } from "react";

    function EmployeeLoad()
    {
      const [id, setId] = useState('');
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
      const [mobile, setMobile] = useState("");
    
    
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=>
    {
      Load();
    },[])
    
    
    
    
      async function  Load()
      {
         const result = await axios.get(
             "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees");
             setUsers(result.data);
             console.log(result.data);
      }
     
        
         async function save(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        try
            {
             await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/save",
            {
            
              name: name,
              address: address,
              mobile: mobile
            
            });
              alert("Employee Registation Successfully");
              setId("");
              setName("");
              setAddress("");
              setMobile("");
            
            
            }
        catch(err)
            {
              alert("User Registation Failed");
            }
       }
       async function editEmployee(users)
       {
        setName(users.name);
        setAddress(users.address);
        setMobile(users.mobile); 
     
        setId(users.id);
        
       }
    
    
       async function update(event)
       {
        event.preventDefault();
    
       try
           {
            
            await axios.patch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update/"+ users.id,
           {
             id: id,
             name: name,
             address: address,
             mobile: mobile
           
           });
             alert("Employee Registation Successfully");
             setId("");
             setName("");
             setAddress("");
             setMobile("");
           
           
           }
       catch(err)
           {
             alert("User Registation Failed");
           }
      }
    
    
      return (
        <div>
           <h1>Employee Details</h1>
           <div class="container mt-4" >
              <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                   <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="employee_id" 
                   value={id}
                   onChange={(event) =>
                    {
                      setId(event.target.value);      
                    }}
                   
                   />
                    <label>employeeName</label>
                    <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeName"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(event) =>
                      {
                        setName(event.target.value);      
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>employeeAddress</label>
                    <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeAddress" 
                     value={address}
                      onChange={(event) =>
                        {
                          setAddress(event.target.value);      
                        }}
                    />
                  </div>
    
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mobile</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeMobile" 
                      value={mobile}
                    onChange={(event) =>
                      {
                        setMobile(event.target.value);      
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
    
                     <div>
                  <button   class="btn btn-primary mt-4"  onClick={save}>Register</button>
                  <button   class="btn btn-primary mt-4"  onClick={update}>Update</button>
                  </div>   
                </form>
              </div>
    
    <table class="table table-dark" align="center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Employee Id</th>
          <th scope="col">Employee Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Employee Address</th>
          <th scope="col">Employee Mobile</th>
          
          <th scope="col">Option</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
           {users.map(function fn(item)
           {
                return(
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{item.id} </th>
                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                    <td>{item.address}</td>
                    <td>{item.mobile}</td> 
                  
                    <td>
                    
    
    
    
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"  onClick={() => editEmployee(item)} >Edit</button>)}    
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" >Delete </button>
                    </td>
    
    
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                );
                })}
                </table>
                    </div>
                );
            }
     
    export default EmployeeLoad;
```

while Running the code this error displayed

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // You can await here
    const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state
```

Comment: it's not a react problem
did you publish your api?
which webserver did you use?

Comment: yes . laravel api it is working i tested through postman. other things are working update only not working

Comment: What is your user at the location of the lines:

 try
           {
            
            await axios.patch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update/"+ users.id,
           {

The user.id is undefined, that's why the API responds with an error

Comment: yes it is undefined so how to solve this

Comment: What is your users object?

Comment: Can you log the users object after the Load function completes fetching?

Comment: while i running the code i got the error i attached above please be check bro on the usereffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no users.id and that's why the dynamically-constructed path is wrong and the API rejects it. http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update/undefined

The error is thrown because of this line:

```
await axios.patch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update/"+ users.id,
           {
             id: id,
             name: name,
             address: address,
             mobile: mobile
           });
```

You can try to await the call to the Load function in the useEffect.

Also, try adding `if (!users) {return null;}`

before the main JSX return.

I think there's something wrong with what your API returns.

Check what the users variable contains.

Something like:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {useEffect, useState } from "react";

function EmployeeLoad()
{
  const [id, setId] = useState('');
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState("");


const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(async ()=>
{
  await Load();
},[])




  async function  Load()
  {
     const result = await axios.get(
         "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees");
         setUsers(result.data);
         console.log(result.data);
  }
 
    
     async function save(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    try
        {
         await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/save",
        {
        
          name: name,
          address: address,
          mobile: mobile
        
        });
          alert("Employee Registation Successfully");
          setId("");
          setName("");
          setAddress("");
          setMobile("");
        
        
        }
    catch(err)
        {
          alert("User Registation Failed");
        }
   }
   async function editEmployee(users)
   {
    setName(users.name);
    setAddress(users.address);
    setMobile(users.mobile); 
 
    setId(users.id);
    
   }


   async function update(event)
   {
    event.preventDefault();

   try
       {

        console.log('Let Aifos Si Prahs know what is here', users);
        
        await axios.patch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update/"+ users.find(u => u.id === id).id || id,
       {
         id: id,
         name: name,
         address: address,
         mobile: mobile
       
       });
         alert("Employee Registation Successfully");
         setId("");
         setName("");
         setAddress("");
         setMobile("");
       
       
       }
   catch(err)
       {
         alert("User Registation Failed");
       }
  }


  if (users.length <= 0) return null;

  return (
    <div>
       <h1>Employee Details</h1>
       <div class="container mt-4" >
          <form>
              <div class="form-group">
               <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="employee_id" 
               value={id}
               onChange={(event) =>
                {
                  setId(event.target.value);      
                }}
               
               />
                <label>employeeName</label>
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeName"
                value={name}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  {
                    setName(event.target.value);      
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>employeeAddress</label>
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeAddress" 
                 value={address}
                  onChange={(event) =>
                    {
                      setAddress(event.target.value);      
                    }}
                />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mobile</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeMobile" 
                  value={mobile}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  {
                    setMobile(event.target.value);      
                  }}
                />
              </div>

                 <div>
              <button   class="btn btn-primary mt-4"  onClick={save}>Register</button>
              <button   class="btn btn-primary mt-4"  onClick={update}>Update</button>
              </div>   
            </form>
          </div>

<table class="table table-dark" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Employee Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Employee Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Employee Address</th>
      <th scope="col">Employee Mobile</th>
      
      <th scope="col">Option</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
       {users.map(function fn(item)
       {
            return(
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <th scope="row">{item.id} </th>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.address}</td>
                <td>{item.mobile}</td> 
              
                <td>
                



                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"  onClick={() => editEmployee(item)} >Edit</button>)}    
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" >Delete </button>
                </td>


                </tr>
            </tbody>
            );
            })}
            </table>
                </div>
            );
        }
 
export default EmployeeLoad;
```

Althoug this won't help if your users object doesn't contain an id.

Comment: i tried  but how to call this inside the useEffect can you write it it will helpful for me thanks

Comment: I;ll update  my answer, in the mean time, what do you see in place of <th scope="row">{item.id} </th> on the page?

Comment: yes..............] dude

Comment: Also, your users vraible is an array, how come can you call it like users.id? That's wrong! Do you need a specific employee's id to update his data in the DB? Then just use id, not users.id

Comment: so how to write it bro

Comment: I'll help you, but I need to know what is the content of the users variable.

मैं आपकी मदद करूंगा, लेकिन मुझे यह जानने की जरूरत है कि उपयोगकर्ता चर की सामग्री क्या है।

Comment: Try it with the code that I've included in this answer

Comment: Just copy-paste this code instead of yours

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of what you see on this page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250310/discussion-between-nanda-kumar-and-aifos-si-prahs).